# chrome codeigniter redis clearing session issue

Tags: codeigniter, session, redis

I am using the following settings for sessions in codeigniter.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://localhost:6379';//BASEPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I am unable to logout and clear session on chrome (working fine on FF and safari ) by using the following

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this -> session -> set_userdata('customer_login', false );
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting . try redis-cli monitor (if it is receiving any command )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it with this

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->cache->clean();
ob_clean();
redirect('controller/method'); # or route
```

---

**In your case**

- I don't think setting `$this->session->set_userdata('customer_login', false );` is good way to check user logged.
- When ever user logged use `'logged_in' => TRUE` in session array and in method you can check `if($this->session->userdata('item') == true )`

Comment: This is not working on my chrome. i am still logged in even after i remove everything from cache

Comment: how you say that you logged in again ?? show me your login method

Comment: Login code is: $this -> session -> set_userdata('customer_login', $result );  where $result is user data. and below is logout code. 
        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
  redirect(base_url(''), 'refresh' );

Comment: sir i am using this code :  $this -> session -> set_userdata('customer_login', $result ); where $result is user data.

Comment: just add my code to logout and redirect to home page. Once he click back check is he logged in if not throw out